# T-SQL Query for Calculating Sum of two rows and Substract sum of Previous rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was wondering how this Query can be written. I tried with Rank and Preceeding in SQL Server 2019 but could not come up with the result. I have the following table structure and data:

```
USE [tempdb]
GO

CREATE TABLE #Orders(
    [RowID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Ordercount] [int] NULL,
    [OrderDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

   SET IDENTITY_INSERT #Orders ON 
   GO


     INSERT #Orders ([RowID], [Ordercount], [OrderDate]) VALUES (1, 576, CAST(N'2021-02-04T09:21:22.620' 
     AS DateTime))

     INSERT #Orders ([RowID], [Ordercount], [OrderDate]) VALUES (2, 632, CAST(N'2021-02-04T09:21:38.770' 
     AS DateTime))

    INSERT #Orders ([RowID], [Ordercount], [OrderDate]) VALUES (3, 788, CAST(N'2021-02-04T09:21:51.040' 
    AS DateTime))

    INSERT #Orders ([RowID], [Ordercount], [OrderDate]) VALUES (4, 976, CAST(N'2021-02-04T09:22:09.637' AS 
    DateTime))

    INSERT #Orders ([RowID], [Ordercount], [OrderDate]) VALUES (5, 1032, CAST(N'2021-02-04T09:22:34.873' 
    AS DateTime))

    INSERT #Orders ([RowID], [Ordercount], [OrderDate]) VALUES (6, 1200, CAST(N'2021-02-04T09:22:47.853' 
    AS DateTime))

   SET IDENTITY_INSERT #Orders OFF


   Select * from #Orders
   Order by OrderDate Desc
```

What I need is the Sum of the first two rows count - Sum of the preceeding row count in a separate column, for example in the data above it will be

```
Select (1200+1032) - (976+788) `enter code here`--468
Select (976+788) - (632+576) --556
```

Is it possible to write a query with Lag and Rank and other functions or other methods.

Thanks much
Ak

Comment: check this out, it might help
https://stevestedman.com/2013/04/rows-and-range-preceding-and-following/

Comment: So for every row you want `(currentrow + prevrow1) - (prevrow2 + prevrow3)`?

Comment: Yes, thats correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use three `LAG` functions together. I assume the ordering is as you wrote at the bottom of your code. Not sure what you want to do for the first 3 rows, I have set a default of zero: the syntax is: `LAG(expression, offset, default) OVER (...`

```sql
Select *,
    MySum = Ordercount
        + LAG(OrderCount, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate DESC)
        - LAG(OrderCount, 2, 0) OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate DESC)
        - LAG(OrderCount, 3, 0) OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate DESC)
from #Orders
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
drop table if exists #Orders;
go
CREATE TABLE #Orders(
    [RowID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Ordercount] [int] NULL,
    [OrderDate] [datetime] NULL);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #Orders ON;
INSERT #Orders ([RowID], [Ordercount], [OrderDate]) VALUES 
(1, 576, CAST(N'2021-02-04T09:21:22.620' AS DateTime)),
(2, 632, CAST(N'2021-02-04T09:21:38.770' AS DateTime)),
(3, 788, CAST(N'2021-02-04T09:21:51.040' AS DateTime)),
(4, 976, CAST(N'2021-02-04T09:22:09.637' AS DateTime)),
(5, 1032, CAST(N'2021-02-04T09:22:34.873' AS DateTime)),
(6, 1200, CAST(N'2021-02-04T09:22:47.853' AS DateTime));
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #Orders OFF;

with
two_cte as (
    select *, (row_number() over (order by OrderDate)+1)/2 two_grp           
    from #Orders),
agg_cte as (
    select tc.two_grp, sum(OrderCount) Ordercount,
           max(RowID) max_RowID, min(RowID) min_RowID,
           row_number() over (order by tc.two_grp desc) rn
    from two_cte tc
    group by tc.two_grp)
select two_grp, max_RowID, min_RowID,
       Ordercount-LAG(OrderCount, 1, null) OVER (ORDER BY rn desc) calc_col
from agg_cte
order by two_grp desc;
```

```
two_grp max_RowID   min_RowID   calc_col
3       6           5           468
2       4           3           556
1       2           1           NULL
```